# tree iterations c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Looking for examples on simple tree iterations in C++, both recursive and iterative. (post, pre and in-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/) shows an example of a binary tree and how to iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

The Adobe Source Library's [`adobe::forest<T>`](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__tutorials__forest.html) is a generic tree container that can be iterated post- pre- or in-order. The documentation has examples of how to accomplish these different types of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

if your tree looks like this:

```
struct Node{
    Node *left, *right, *parent;

    int value; // or some other important data :-)
}
```

then this is how you make a recursive in-order iteration:

```
void iterate(Node *n){
    if(!n)
        return;

    iterate(n->left);
    cout << n->value; // do something with the value
    iterate(n->right);
}
```

If you swap the lines with n->left and n->right the tree will be iterated in reverse order.

These are the pre-order and post-order iterations:

```
void iterate_pre(Node *n){
    if(!n)
        return;

    cout << n->value; // do something with the value
    iterate_pre(n->left);
    iterate_pre(n->right);
}

void iterate_post(Node *n){
    if(!n)
        return;

    iterate_post(n->left);
    iterate_post(n->right);
    cout << n->value; // do something with the value
}
```

The non-recursive iteration is a little bit more complicated.
First thing you need is to find a first node in the tree (like `vector<T>::begin()`)

```
Node *find_first(Node *tree){
    Node *tmp;
    while(tree){
        tmp = tree;
        tree = tree->left
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Then you need a way to get the next item of the tree (`vector<T>::iterator::operator++()`).

```
Node *next(Node *n){
    assert(n);

    if(n->right)
        return find_first(n->right)

    while(n->parent && n->parent->right == n)
        n = n->parent;

    if(!n->parent)
        return NULL;

    return n;
}
```

(this function tries to find a first node in the right subtree and if it's not possible, goes up the tree until the path comes from the right subtree)

Comment: Your iterate_pre and iterate_post should call themselves instead of iterate.